# Error in installing compiled wireshark 1.10.2 on Kali 1.0

Tags: wireshark, compile, kali-linux

I've downloaded source code of Wireshark 1.10.2 from it offical website and compile it by following commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

It was compiled and installed successfully, but when I've opened it, this message was appeared and not interface is listed:

> wireshark: error while loading shared libraries: libwiretap.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I fix it? I'm using Kali 1.0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. The solution is runnind `ldconfig` before ruuning wireshark. One time is sufficient. So first execute:

```
ldconfig
```

and then run wireshark.